# Is there a way to get a command line interface to wipe clean?

Tags: python, user-interface, command, command-line-interface

I have a command line interface in python as a project and would like to be able to get my terminal to wipe clean after it has completed delivering a set of instructions. Is there a command for this?

Comment: You mean clear the terminal window?

Comment: In iPython, typing `cls` will clear the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to clear the terminal from your python code, you can use `os.system("clear")` on linux or `os.system("cls")` on windows.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your wish properly, but with the intention of helping, if your command line interface is running in a ***REPL*** ( Read, Evaluate, Print and Loop) interface - a python shell to execute a single python command and display the result - then the commands used to clear the terminal or Python shell are `cls` and `clear`.

Depending on your OS, you can run the following:

***Windows***

```
import os
os.system(‘CLS’)
```

***Linux***

```
import os
os.system(‘clear’)
```

For more details you can check this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-clear-python-shell#:%7E:text=The%20commands%20used%20to%20clear,shell%20are%20cls%20and%20clear.)

I hope it was of some help!

Answer (score -1):

What IDE are you using? With the Spyder IPython console, you can use CTRL + L.